# Attempting two pass two objects through @PathVariable in thymeleaf/spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm attempting to pull two parameters with the @PathVariable annotation but have been unsuccessful due to java throwing me an error about it referencing the item id (which I currently has as an Long) as a String.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}")
    public String buyToner(Model model, @PathVariable("tid") Long tid,
                           @PathVariable("bid") Long bid){


        //Grab info
        Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(bid);
        Toner mToner = tonerService.findOneToner(tid);

        //Updating qualities
        mToner.setTonerQuantity(mToner.getTonerQuantity() - 1);
        mBuyer.setBalance(mBuyer.getBalance() - mToner.getTonerPrice());

        Buyer iBuyer = new Buyer();
        iBuyer.getToners().add(mToner);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

View:

```
 <form th:action="@{/purchaseToner/{tid}(tid=${toner.id})/{bid}(bid=${buyer.buyerId})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                       <select th:object="${toner}">
                            <option>Select a Toner</option>
                            <option th:each="toner : ${toners}"
                                    th:text="${toner.tonerName}"
                                    th:value="${toner.id}">
                            </option>
                       </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="buyerId"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Purchase" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to make this purchase?')"/>
                    </form>
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-06-05 21:10:59.418  INFO 788 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-05 21:10:59.517  INFO 788 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-05 21:10:59.527  INFO 788 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Started Application in 18.596 seconds (JVM running for 19.548)
2017-06-05 21:11:06.438  INFO 788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-06-05 21:11:06.439  INFO 788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-06-05 21:11:06.470  INFO 788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 31 ms
2017-06-05 21:11:09.673  INFO 788 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-06-05 21:11:15.837  WARN 788 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{tid}(tid=${toner.id})"
```

Comment: Can you run this code in your controller and try? `@PostMapping("/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}")
    public String buyToner(Model model, @PathVariable("tid") String tid,
                           @PathVariable("bid") String bid){

      Long extractedTid = Long.valueOf(tid).longValue();
      Long extractedBid = Long.valueOf(bid).longValue();

      //Grab info
       Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(extractedBid);
       Toner mToner = tonerService.findOneToner(extractedTid);
    
}`

Comment: Why do you want to add two objects? Toner object can be added as a model attribute while keeping "buyer" as form object

Comment: Your url in the thymleaf template is flawed. You should first define your properties then substitute them. Something like `@{/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}(tid=${toner.id},bid=${buyer.buyerId})` should do the trick. See the Thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change th:action to following

```
<form th:action="@{/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}(tid=${toner.id},bid=${buyer.buyerId})}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
```

Also, you need to add toner to spring model. In your code, It is not in the model

Answer (score 0):

Your api **buyToner** has not been receiving inputs in path variable as number. There is nothing wrong with your api service; check your client side code, is it sending request in proper format **OR** have you tested your api with any restclient ?

Check out the java exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{tid}(tid=${toner.id})"
```

input is not a number here. AND WHY ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change this:**

```
@PostMapping("/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}")
    public String buyToner(Model model, @PathVariable("tid") Long tid,
                           @PathVariable("bid") Long bid){
...
    }
```

**into this:**

```
@PostMapping("/purchaseToner/{tid}/{bid}")
    public String buyToner(Model model, @PathVariable("tid") String tid,
                           @PathVariable("bid") String bid){

        long bidlong = Long.parseLong(bid)
        long tidlong = Long.parseLong(tid)

        //Grab info
        Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(bid);
        Toner mToner = tonerService.findOneToner(tid);

        ...
    }
```

***In other words, change your controller's parameters into String types, then convert them into Long.***

Comment: A small correction. 
       `Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(mBuyer);
        Toner mToner = tonerService.findOneToner(mToner);` **not** 

`Buyer mBuyer = buyerService.findOne(bid);
        Toner mToner = tonerService.findOneToner(tid);`